# making Transparent, unclickable areas in a userControl/pictureBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have a userControl with a picturebox in it. I need the areas of the userControl to be transparent and unclickable on the main form. After some searching Ive come up with this. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235175(VS.60).aspx
but it doesn't seem to work. I have it set up so the usercontrol can be drag-and-dropped. but I dont want transparent areas to be dragable.

Comment: Well, no, that won't work, because it's VB6, which is pretty much an entirely different language to all the VBs since 2001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx

Comment: This is useful!, you must create a region to have your Transparent and unclickable area in your usercontrol. Copy and paste the example from Microsoft website and uncomment 1 line:

     'e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, newRectangle)